# First segment of my segment controller doesn't respond

Tags: ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a settings screen with a couple of segmented controls on it. All was well until I added a third. Now the new one works, and the top one works, but the one in the middle doesn't...

It used to work fine, but now the first segment doesn't respond. If I click on segments 2 through 4 my controller's method is called as expected. If I click on the first segment... nothing.

I suspect there is another flag somewhere that I hit by mistake, but I can't find it. Yes, all of the segments are Enabled. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your segment possibly covered by another UI widget? Code sample?

Comment: No code to sample. I looked at the display, there are other objects on the screen but I can't see how it could be covering only one part of it. I'll see though, maybe it's something non-obvious.

Comment: Do you have a navigation item, a space, or maybe a titleView? How about a screen shot?

Comment: You got it, you should promote that to an answer (can I do that?). The problem was the element in question had no visible UI. I only found it by cursoring through the elements in the view hierarchy list until I noticed one that was very small and basically invisible.

Comment: Thanks. Done. Check-out Spark Inspector! I will remove this last comment if you approve the answer to clean up this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking through the hierarchy in detail: the tap is possibly trapped by a partially **overlapping view**.

If a tap does not respond because the size of an element changes, it may because it is hidden by one of these:

1. an unconventionally long navigation item
2. a view with no visible content
3. a title view

This amazing tool has saved me time and again: [Spark Inspector](http://sparkinspector.com/). It shows you the intricate overlapping layers of all your UIViews.

Comment: Spark is the most useful thing ever. Everyone vote this up, it will definitely help other users too.